# translate string into function argument

Tags: python

While applying some external module method to a class I need to be able to pass different pairs of `arg = 'value'` to the function, like:

```
Ad.nodes.get(id_ = '11974312')
```

How to pass dicts or tuples to the function, so that it recognises `'id_'` (string) as `id_` (argument) in
`('id_', '11974312')` (tuple) or `{'id_':'11974312'}` (dictionary) ?

Basically, I just need to get `id_` out of `'id_'`

For your reference, I am trying to use neomodel module for neo4j graph db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a dictionary to a function that accepts \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559638/how-to-send-a-dictionary-to-a-function-that-accepts-kwargs)

Answer (score 2):

To pass multiple arguments to a function, you use the `*` operator and `**` operator as shown below.

```
def myfoo(*arg, **karg):
    print arg, karg
```

The `*` operator pack all ordered argument in it, and the `**` operator packs all unmatched key argument in it.

For example:

```
def myfoo(a, *arg):
    return a, arg

myfoo(11,22,33)
>> (11, [22, 33])
myfoo(11)
>> (11, [])
```

For key argument it works the same way,

```
def myfoo(a=11, b=22, **kargs):
    return a, b, kargs

myfoo(22, c=100, b=233)
>> (22, 233, {'c': 100})
```

([ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527670/10035556))

Comment: I was misunderstood for how I defined my question initially, please consider my edited question again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can unfold the positional argument of a function with a single asterisk `*` and unfold dictionaries as key/value pairs with two asterisks `**`. For example

```
def get(a, b, c=0):
    print(a, b, c)

args = (1, 2)
kwargs = {'c': 3}

get(*args, **kwargs)
```

The [Python Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) has details on this.

**A more specific example for OP**

If you have a function `get(id_=None)` with the *keyword argument* `id_` you can use `**some_dict` to unfold the key/value pairs into keyword arguments. For example

```
In [1]: def get(id_=None): 
   ...:     print(id_) 
   ...:     # do something with id_ ... 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: get(**{'id_': 1})                                                                                                                                                                                 
1

In [3]: get(**{'id_': 2})                                                                                                                                                                                 
2
```

If instead you have a function `get(id_)` with the *positional argument* `id_` you can use `*some_iterable` to unfold the values into positional arguments. You can also use `**some_dict` to unfold the key/value pairs as long as the keys *exactly match* the positional arguments. For example

```
In [4]: def get(id_): 
   ...:     print(id_) 
   ...:     # do something with id_ ... 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [5]: get(*(1,))                                                                                                                                                                                        
1

In [6]: get(*(2,))                                                                                                                                                                                        
2

In [7]: get(**{'id_': 3})                                                                                                                                                                                 
3

In [8]: # this will fail because `id` is not the argument, `id_` is
In [9]: get(**{'id': 4})                                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-922e10531f8a> in <module>
----> 1 get(**{'id': 4})

TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

Comment: I was misunderstood for how I defined my question initially, please consider my edited question again. Thank you.